# What shaders are used in the example below to achieve the same effect?

Tags: shaders

Everthing I have done in blender is all pretty standard as far as shaders & textures go but I want to start working on toon shaders I have a style in mind but so far I havent been able to find any usefull resources to gte me there. Any help would be greatly appriciated!

[image: Style I want]

Answer (score 3):

The simple shading can be achieved with "Toon BSDF" for the material and the "Freestyle" mode in the scene settings.

[image: Toon BSDF]

[image: Freestyle]

[image: Toon effects applied]

Answer (score 1):

The effect is called [chromatic aberration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_aberration). It separates blue from red and makes things blurry as well. It becomes stronger with the distance from the center. This is a property of the lens.

In Blender, you'd not achieve this with a shader. You'd use a compositing node called "Lens distortion" and set the "dispersion" value to something larger than 0.

[image: Chromatic aberration]

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I'd normall do this in after effects but that wasnt actually what I was intrested in, More the outlined style judging from other shots and previous experience im 90% certain this was made using 3d software not traditional animation